# Do email servers have standard folder naming or ids?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, imap, swiftmailer

I'm trying to append sent emails to the "Sent" folder in different email accounts running in different servers (yahoo, gmail, outlook, etc.)

For that purpose, I'm using the `imap_append` function where I have to give the name of the folder I want to append the emails.

The problem is that every account has different folder naming and languages. For example, Gmail has `[Gmail]\Sent`, a Spanish Yahoo account has `Enviados`, etc.

Is there a solution for this? I have tried to send the emails to `INBOX.Sent` but not working at all.
Is the only solution asking the user to define his "Sent" folder?

Edit:
I have checked the tags for the [Gmail]\Sent folder in a Gmail account and I don't know why it has no \Sent flag defined. How are mail clients supposed to know that the sent emails should be copied here?

[image]

Comment: See [RFC6154](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6154) which some servers support to tell you what their Special folders are.  On some servers, it’s just seeing what folder has the \Sent tag when you do a LIST command.

Comment: Thanks for the resource provided, it was useful.

I looped all folders with the PHP method `imap_getmailboxes` but the flags are not returned.
Any ideas on how we can find the folder with `\Sent` flag?

Comment: That list is all the supported flags messages in a folder, not the flags of a folder.  I don't know if php IMAP supports folder special use flags, or folder flags at all.  Its not very extensible since it's built on an old C library, rather than being implemented with sockets.